# How to read parent key from child key in yaml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, yaml

I am having a yaml file as below if I pass Login(child key)to a function then it should return parent key ie (id) using Javascript.

```
id:
 Login: 'LoginText'
 Password: 'passwordText'

css:
 LoginButton: 'LoginButton'
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Are you against 3rd party packages? A quick search on NPM revealed quite a few libraries that already solve this issue.